# Conditional Attributes for Django User based on Groups

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

A given `user` can be in zero or more of the following categories:

- `floor staff`
- `managers`
- `owners`

If the user is `floor staff` they require extra attributes (e.g. `seniority` and `staffType`).

My initial attempt looked something like this:

- Create a `Group` for each category (this seems to make sense since each type of user should have different permissions within the site)
- Create a `FloorStaff` model with the required extra attributes and a 1-to-1 relationship with `User`
- Handle `User` creation and `FloorStaff` creation separately (i.e. using separate forms, accessed separately). The form to create `FloorStaff` adds the `User` to the `floor staff` group automatically.

While this works, it is not the most intuitive way to add a new floor staff employee to the site. From a manager's perspective, filling out 2 forms to add one employee makes little sense. That is, if I hire someone new, I should be able to fill out a "new employee" form that includes adding said employee to the correct categor(y/ies) at the same time as adding their basic info, and, if that employee is to be `floor staff` then the extra attributes should be added as well.

I've been toying with creating a custom user model that includes the extra attributes, but this feels wrong given that not all `User`s are `FloorStaff`.

At this point all I can think to do is to build a custom view and HTML form, but that too seems to go against the Django way of thinking.

What is the most "Djangoific" way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making seniority and staffType as optional fields, and then create a custom model admin that enforces  providing those fields when floor staff is true

Comment: May I ask your reasoning?

Comment: Thats the easiest and most 'by the book' way I see for doing this.
You use exisiting classes, and explicitly describe the 'laws' for the model.
The only drawback I see is that the end result wouldnt be enforced by the database - only the admin, and so If you will you somthing like Django-Rest-Framework, It wouldnt know about your modeladmin class.
If you dont have such use-cases, its the best option.

Comment: Ah, cool, alright. I do plan on eventually adding on the DRF, but I suppose I'll cross that bridge when I get to it.